# Converting a string of JS Array to PHP array

Tags: php, javascript

I have a string (in PHP) representing a JS array, and for testing purpose would like to convert it to a PHP array to feed them into a unit test. Here's an example string

```
{ name: 'unique_name',fof: -1,range: '1',aoe: ',0,0,fp: '99,desc: 'testing ability,image: 'dummy.jpg'}
```

I could use a explode on the "," then on the colon, but that is rather inelegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is not valid json.  `json_decode()` will not work.  Before considering testing, spend time correcting the json payload syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$php_object = json_decode($javascript_array_string)
```

This will return an object, with properties corresponding to the javascript array's properties. If you want an associative array, pass true as a second parameter to json_decode

```
$php_array = json_decode($javascript_array_string, true)
```

There is also a json_encode function for going the other way.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [**json_decode()**](http://de3.php.net/json_decode).

Answer (score 0):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

The above example will output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```